# RefreshControl's attributed title not showing when called programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a `UITableViewController` with a refresh control. When you pull down, it works fine—the spinner spins, the title shows and things work. But when I trigger the control programmatically with the following code the attributed title does not display:

```
-(void)startRefreshControl
{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y - self.refreshControl.frame.size.height - 5) animated:YES];
    [self refreshFeeds];
}
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was setting the attributed string's color to white somewhere else in the code.

Comment: LOL, same here. Thanks